# Positive definiteness of a symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is an $n\times n$ square matrix with main diagonal $1,2,\dots,n$, secondary diagonals $1,2,\dots,n-1$, tertiary diagonals $1,2,\dots,n-2$, and so on. For example, if we take $n=5$ then $$\mathbf{A}=\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&1&1\\
1&2&2&2&2\\
1&2&3&3&3\\
1&2&3&4&4\\
1&2&3&4&5
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Clearly this real matrix is symmetric thus Hermitian, and therefore all its eigenvalues are real. I am trying to show that this type of matrix has all positive eigenvalues. Numerical experiments suggest that this is the case but I can't find a formal proof. Gershgorin circle theorem definitely won't help here and positive definiteness is basically an equivalent problem. So, how can I prove that every eigenvalue of $\mathbf{A}$ is positive?

Comment: I have answered this question on MathOverFlow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212898/any-interesting-properties-of-the-matrix-m-m-ij-with-m-ij-mini-j/212909#212909

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me copy my answer to the MathOverFlow question mentioned in the comment.

---

Let $B=(b_{ij})$ be the upper triangular matrix such that
$b_{ij}=
\begin{cases}
1, \textrm{if $i \leq j$}\\
0, \textrm{else}
\end{cases}$, then the matrix $A$ is equal to the product $B^{T}B$.

---

It follows immediately that $A$ is positive definite.

Answer (score 2):

Apply [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion): a Hermitian matrix $M$ is positive definite if and only if each of its principal minors is positive.
The $k$-th principal minor is the determinant of the upper left $k\times k$ 'corner' matrix obtained from $M$.

In this case, for each principal minor, it's very simple to use row reduction so that the determinant is that of an upper triangular matrix with diagonal entries equal to $1$.
For instance, if we were calculating the $5$-th principal minor of some $A$ with $n\geqslant 5$ we'd have

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&1&1\\
1&2&2&2&2\\
1&2&3&3&3\\
1&2&3&4&4\\
1&2&3&4&5
\end{bmatrix}
\implies
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&1&1\\
0&1&1&1&1\\
0&1&2&2&2\\
0&1&2&3&3\\
0&1&2&3&4
\end{bmatrix}
$$

by subtracting the first row from the rows below it.
Proceeding,

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&1&1\\
0&1&1&1&1\\
0&1&2&2&2\\
0&1&2&3&3\\
0&1&2&3&4
\end{bmatrix}
\implies
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&1&1\\
0&1&1&1&1\\
0&0&1&1&1\\
0&0&1&2&2\\
0&0&1&2&3
\end{bmatrix}
$$

by subtracting the second row from the rows below it.
And so on and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

It's wise to try and use the symmetry of this matrix.

Recall that elementary row/column operations preserve the determinant

Consider subtracting the first column from each other column.

We then get
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0\\
1&1&1&1&1\\
1&1&2&2&2\\
1&1&2&3&3\\
1&1&2&3&4
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Then, subtracting the first row from each row gives a block matrix where the lower right block is the same matrix but with one less dimension. Now apply induction.